# What is the way quorum majority is decided in FCI with file share?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

In WSFC FCI with 2 nodes and file share, each node participates in a heart beat.

The file share is a voting witness, and connectivity from any node to that share is counted as an affirmative vote. More than one-half of the possible votes must be affirmative for the cluster to be healthy.

So this mean - in a 2 node fci with 1 file share, each node sends its heart beat to the cluster and its connectivity to witness is counted as 1 vote. So each node effectively sends 2 votes to the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

> In WSFC FCI with 2 nodes and file share, each node participates in a heart beat.

It would be correct to sat that each node participates in "Quorum" not heartbeat. [Heartbeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/high-availability/private-heartbeat-configuration-on-cluster-server) is method of communication while [Quorum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-quorum-modes-and-voting-configuration-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is kind of "vote/understanding" that is reached in WSFC.

> So this mean - in a 2 node fci with 1 file share, each node sends its heart beat to the cluster and its connectivity to witness is counted as 1 vote.

Assuming all nodes are voting in WSFC, in 2 node 1 FS configuration. Each node will present its votes and this will be counted as 1 vote( 1 vote from each node) and 1 vote will come from FS witness so total votes will be 3 votes. Each node can "only" give 1 vote not 2 votes.

Please read the links shared.

Comment: In a 2 node 1 file share cluster, what is the point of the single vote of file share? For example - if node 2 goes down, yet we have 2 votes (node 1's and file share's vote) thereby keeping the cluster alive, but we don't have HA because if the node 1 crashes then there is nothing to fall back to.

Comment: If the vote from FS is not there so there will be only 2 votes from each node. Now let us assume one node goes down so now you have 1 vote ONLY. For quorum to work you should have more than 50% which mean more than 1 vote to be there. with just 2 nodes voting and one node down the WSFC will loose quorum and will come down. "I strongly suggest you to read the links"

Comment: I was hoping there should be some kind of alert in a situation where file share and node 2 go down rather than taking the cluster down when node 1 is working perfectly fine.

Comment: No there is no inbuilt alert from cluster GUI, but starting from [Windows server 2012 you have dynamic quorum and witness feature](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4440/understand-how-dynamic-witness-works-for-a-sql-server-wfsc/) which removes vote from node when it goes down. Helping cluster to keep running with "last man standing".

Comment: The dynamic vote of file share seems to be valid only based on the initial membership (`If you have an even number of nodes plus witness, the witness votes, so the total is odd.` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#dynamic-quorum-behavior). So if there are 2 nodes and 1 file share, then the majority is 2. Irrespective of whether the node or fileshare goes down. I think the dynamic thing is at the time of config and not after a node goes down. Do you have any hands-on experience about this?

Comment: I think you are right as explained in the example immediately below the above link

Comment: Although here they are not saying what happens when witness goes down - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#two-nodes-with-a-witness